# android 4.1.1 developer options dissapeared

Tags: android

I have a new Android 4.1.1
I managed to enable Developer Options USB Debug in the settings menu.
This morning there doesn't seem to be a developer options, it was there yesterday.
Last night I spent a while going through all the multitude of aps trying to get rid of them.
Perhaps that's also got rid of developer options.
Any ideas
Thanks
Jim

Comment: in settings -> about -> double click on 'build number' can help to 'open' developer options menu.

Comment: What device you are using ?

Comment: Lack of research, answer is in the first link when you search `android 4.1.1 developer options` on Google...

Answer (score 1):

Developer options in the new Android are actually hidden,

To access the Developer Options menu, and things like USB debugging, just do the following:

- Open the Settings menu
- Go down to the "System" sub-section of the settings menu at the bottom
- Hit "About Phone [or Tablet]"
- At or near the bottom, you should see the "Build number" header
- Tap this area 7 times, and the Developer Options menu should appear

Comment: Never work, I got the same issue but as you mentioned tap 7 times doesn't seems work at all. Not sure this should be right direction to get solution for this issue.